# asp.net mvc - Set locale / format of a DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the bootrap datetime picker to allow the user to enter a date, show below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="end">Start date:</label><br />
    <div class='input-group date' id='dt1'>
        @Html.TextBox("StartDateFilter", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dt1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L',
        locale: 'en-GB'
    });
</script>
```

This date then gets picked up as a parameter in the following method signature:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string sortBy, string currentFilter, string searchString, string filterType, int? itemDisplay, int? page, DateTime? startDateFilter, DateTime? endDateFilter)
```

However, the date in the textbox is being displayed as DD/MM/YYYY but passed as MM/DD/YYYY which causes several formatting errors and parsing errors. How can I change the format or local of the DateTime objects that are in the parameters to DD/MM/YYYY.

I have already added the following to my web.config file under system.web:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

UPDATED

global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
          new JsonSerializerSettings
      {
         DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
         DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified,
         Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")
      };

         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
    }
```

Comment: I have just tried to add this into the global.asax file and I get: 'GlobalConfiguration' does not exist in the current context. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was System.Web.Http. Just trying to install the package for it, but it won't install for some reason, think its a server error so I'll try again in a few minutes and test this answer. I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: After 17 tries I managed to get the package to install haha, don't know what's up with my internet today! Sadly, this didn't fix my problem. The date is still passed as MM/DD/YYY and thus are formatted incorrectly and when using a day which is past 12, this get passsed as null.

Comment: i was having same problem as you , this helped me i have no idea whats going on with yours

Comment: After 10's of hours, I finally came to a solution. I passed the date as a string. Then checked to see if it was null or empty when a user wasn't inputting a filter. Converted it to a date and forced the format to be in UK and then used this new local variable datetime to compare against the model. Probably not the best way, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.ParseExact method to format the input date in your method as follow:

```
DateTime sDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDateFilter.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime eDate = DateTime.ParseExact(endDateFilter.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I don't see how this would help? This would just change the display of the datetimepicker to the french standard.

Comment: Thanks again, but this still isn't quite what I need. This will let you change the DateTime format AFTER it has been passed, but I need to change it before.