# How to serialize into Json C# DateTime value?

Tags: c#, json

I have an object **model** that contains **DateTime** property.
This object is being serialized into Json format by calling

> return Json(model);

as a result, I am getting this string

> "/Date(1474398517910)/"

instead of DateTime. That's because Json doesnt support DateTime format, instead it uses a string.

**Question - how to make this string to look like real date, something like**

> "2016-10-22 12:20 PM"

Thanks?

Comment: Use json.net instead of the default serializer. See [Setting the Default JSON Serializer in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14591750/1260204). Also you want to use ISO8601 for your DateTime instance (which is what json.net will do).

Comment: change `DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat` to `DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34592117/932418

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DataTime obj= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize>(jsonString);
```